# Flask scheduled server refresh

Tags: python, flask, scheduled-tasks

I'm creating a website with Flask, and I want the results on the page to be recalculated every six hours. I tried using `schedule`, but the app doesn't close once it starts running, to allow for the tasks scheduled to be executed. How do I get the app to close so that the other scheduled task can run?

```
def main():
    run_process()
    return "Calculations based on latest update completed."

def display():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=False)

def job():
    main()
    display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    schedule.every(6).hour.do(job)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Flask-script to make a manage command, then have cron run the manage command every 6 hours. I'm assuming you want to update data in your database every 6 hours, then have that data available in your website.

More information on Flask-script can be found [here.](https://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
If you look in the first example with the hello function. You can change the hello function to the code that you want to run.

To run the command, if your python file is named manage.py and your function is named hello() you can have cron run the following command:

```
python manage.py hello
```